# Using ImgBrn.exe in Jenkins ends up crashing with code 255

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

I am using ImgBurn.exe to create an ISO in a Jenkins Job, I execute this exe from exec task from a MSbuild .

Whenever i execute it through command prompt it get pass and the ISO gets Created. But if i try through Jenkins then it fails, It crashes with code 255. Please help me with this.

The account which I am logging in and the one which Jenkins is running has same permission (Administrator privileges )

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Exit code `255` is usually when a path is not found. Without seeing any kind of logs, it's difficult to tell what's happening.

When Jenkins runs a shell step, it's current working directory is the `$WORKSPACE`, which would be different than you just opening command prompt. If you are using relative paths, this may explain why it is not finding some file. Use absolute paths. Or post the full logs here for further analysis

Comment: Hey Slav,
Yes I thought the same but the relative paths are resolved properly, I basically did a copy-paste of the command from jenkins log    into cmd prompt in the same working folder of that particular Job and it works well.

Comment: Try going to Jenkins service properties, log on section, and checking "allow service to interact with desktop", then restart service. I also don't really know what you mean when you say `execute this exe from exec task from a MSbuild`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and finally resolved it.

Jenkins uses a different user to run the imgburn.exe, the settings on your profile are not used by the Jenkins user.

You need to setup an imgburn.ini file, so that the jenkins user also uses the same settings.